# What's a good, non-recursive algorithm to calculate a Cartesian product?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, rebol, cartesian-product

#### Note

This is not a REBOL-specific question. You can answer it in any language.

#### Background

The [REBOL](http://www.rebol.com) language supports the creation of domain-specific languages known as "dialects" in REBOL *parlance*. I've created such a dialect for list comprehensions, which aren't natively supported in REBOL.

A good cartesian product algorithm is needed for list comprehensions.

#### The Problem

I've used meta-programming to solve this, by dynamically creating and then executing a sequence of nested `foreach` statements. It works beautifully. However, because it's dynamic, the code is not very readable. REBOL doesn't do recursion well. It rapidly runs out of stack space and crashes. So a recursive solution is out of the question.

In sum, I want to replace my meta-programming with a readable, non-recursive, "inline" algorithm, if possible. The solution can be in any language, as long as I can reproduce it in REBOL. (I can read just about any programming language: C#, C, C++, Perl, Oz, Haskell, Erlang, whatever.)

I should stress that this algorithm needs to support an arbitrary number of sets to be "joined", since list comprehension can involve any number of sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list1 = qw(1 2);
my @list2 = qw(3 4);
my @list3 = qw(5 6);

# Calculate the Cartesian Product
my @cp = cart_prod(\@list1, \@list2, \@list3);

# Print the result
foreach my $elem (@cp) {
  print join(' ', @$elem), "\n";
}

sub cart_prod {
  my @sets = @_;
  my @result;
  my $result_elems = 1;

  # Calculate the number of elements needed in the result
  map { $result_elems *= scalar @$_ } @sets;
  return undef if $result_elems == 0;

  # Go through each set and add the appropriate element
  # to each element of the result
  my $scale_factor = $result_elems;
  foreach my $set (@sets)
  {
    my $set_elems = scalar @$set;  # Elements in this set
    $scale_factor /= $set_elems;
    foreach my $i (0 .. $result_elems - 1) {
      # Calculate the set element to place in this position
      # of the result set.
      my $pos = $i / $scale_factor % $set_elems;
      push @{$result[$i]}, $$set[ $pos ];
    }
  }

  return @result;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
```

Comment: That looks great! I'm going to wait and see if I get any other responses (for curiosity's sake) before I award the answer, but I think you've got it.

Comment: If you're doing this in Perl, just use Set::CrossProduct

Answer (score 6):

3 times Faster and less memory used (less recycles).

```
cartesian: func [
 d [block! ] 
 /local len set i res

][
 d: copy d
 len: 1
 res: make block! foreach d d [len: len * length? d]
 len: length? d
 until [
  set: clear []
  loop i: len [insert set d/:i/1   i: i - 1]
  res: change/only res copy set
  loop i: len [
   unless tail? d/:i: next d/:i [break]
   if i = 1 [break]
   d/:i: head d/:i
   i: i - 1
  ]
  tail? d/1
 ]
 head res
]
```

Comment: Excellent! You are obviously twice the reboller I am.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, Here's Robert Gamble's answer translated into REBOL:

```
REBOL []

cartesian: func [
    {Given a block of sets, returns the Cartesian product of said sets.}
    sets [block!] {A block containing one or more series! values}
    /local
        elems
        result
        row
][
    result: copy []

    elems: 1
    foreach set sets [
        elems: elems * (length? set)
    ]

    for n 0 (elems - 1) 1 [
        row: copy []
        skip: elems
        foreach set sets [
            skip: skip / length? set
            index: (mod to-integer (n / skip) length? set) + 1 ; REBOL is 1-based, not 0-based
            append row set/(index)
        ]
        append/only result row
    ]

    result
]

foreach set cartesian [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]] [
    print set
]

; This returns the same thing Robert Gamble's solution did:

1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;

print "@$_\n" for getCartesian(
  [qw(1 2)],
  [qw(3 4)],
  [qw(5 6)],
);

sub getCartesian {
#
  my @input = @_;
  my @ret = map [$_], @{ shift @input };

  for my $a2 (@input) {
    @ret = map {
      my $v = $_;
      map [@$v, $_], @$a2;
    }
    @ret;
  }
  return @ret;
}
```

output

```
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 4 5
1 4 6
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 4 5
2 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java code to generate Cartesian product for arbitrary number of sets with arbitrary number of elements.

in this sample the list "ls" contains 4 sets (ls1,ls2,ls3 and ls4)  as you can see "ls" can contain any number of sets with any number of elements.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CartesianProduct {

    private List <List <String>> ls = new ArrayList <List <String>> ();
    private List <String> ls1 = new ArrayList <String> ();
    private List <String> ls2 = new ArrayList <String> ();
    private List <String> ls3 = new ArrayList <String> ();
    private List <String> ls4 = new ArrayList <String> ();

    public List <String> generateCartesianProduct () {
        List <String> set1 = null;
        List <String> set2 = null;

        ls1.add ("a");
        ls1.add ("b");
        ls1.add ("c");

        ls2.add ("a2");
        ls2.add ("b2");
        ls2.add ("c2");

        ls3.add ("a3");
        ls3.add ("b3");
        ls3.add ("c3");
        ls3.add ("d3");

        ls4.add ("a4");
        ls4.add ("b4");

        ls.add (ls1);
        ls.add (ls2);
        ls.add (ls3);
        ls.add (ls4);

        boolean subsetAvailabe = true;
        int setCount = 0;

        try{    
            set1 = augmentSet (ls.get (setCount++), ls.get (setCount));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            if (set1 == null) {
                set1 = ls.get(0);
            }
            return set1;
        }

        do {
            try {
                setCount++;      
                set1 = augmentSet(set1,ls.get(setCount));
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                subsetAvailabe = false;
            }
        } while (subsetAvailabe);
        return set1;
    }

    public List <String> augmentSet (List <String> set1, List <String> set2) {

        List <String> augmentedSet = new ArrayList <String> (set1.size () * set2.size ());
        for (String elem1 : set1) {
            for(String elem2 : set2) {
                augmentedSet.add (elem1 + "," + elem2);
            }
        }
        set1 = null; set2 = null;
        return augmentedSet;
    }

    public static void main (String [] arg) {
        CartesianProduct cp = new CartesianProduct ();
        List<String> cartesionProduct = cp.generateCartesianProduct ();
        for (String val : cartesionProduct) {
            System.out.println (val);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This solution doesn't work. Robert Gamble's is the correct solution.

I brainstormed a bit and came up with this solution:

(I know most of you won't know REBOL, but it's a fairly readable language.)

```
REBOL []

sets: [[1 2 3] [4 5] [6]] ; Here's a set of sets
elems: 1
result: copy []
foreach set sets [elems: elems * (length? set)]
for n 1 elems 1 [
    row: copy []
    foreach set sets [
        index: 1 + (mod (n - 1) length? set)
        append row set/(index)
    ]
    append/only result row
]

foreach row result [
    print result
]
```

This code produces:

```
1 4 6
2 5 6
3 4 6
1 5 6
2 4 6
3 5 6
```

(Upon first reading the numbers above, you may think there are duplicates. I did. But there aren't.)

Interestingly, this code uses almost the very same algorithm (1 + ((n - 1) % 9) that torpedoed my [Digital Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204489/calculate-the-digital-root-of-a-number) question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this algorithm has the problem that it ONLY works on sets with different lengths. Back to the drawing board!